# Как передать значение через preference

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

Например мне нужно узнать какое значение стоит у checkBox (true или false), или какая цифра стоит в поле шрифт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо загрузить дефолтные настройки так (R.xml.preferences - последнее слово - имя файла с разметкой экрана настроек в папке `res/xml/`; `this` - это контекст, активити):

```
//get default settings to get all settings later
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, true);
```

После этого инициализировать SharedPreferences для получения текущих настроек так:

```
//initialize SharedPreferences var
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

И, наконец, получить конкретное значение так ("check_box_preferences" - это значение `key` из разметки настроек):

```
boolean checkBoxValue = this.pref.getBoolean("check_box_preferences", false);
```

Comment: boolean checkBoxValue = this.pref.getBoolean("check_box_preferences", false);
Это проверка на то существует ли такой пункт, а мне нужно узнать значение этого пункта в настройках.(Какое значение true или false);

Comment: @Romag, нет, это как раз таки значение вашего чекбокса - отмечен он или нет

Comment: Если у нас в конце стоит true и значение чек бокса false  то: checkBoxValue = this.pref.getBoolean("check_box_preferences", false); чему будет равно checkboxvalue?

Comment: @Romag, последнее значение в методе `SharedPreferences#getBoolean(String key, boolean defaultValue)` - это значение, которое должен вернуть метод в случае отсутствия записи с указанным в первом аргументе ключом. Т.е., если у вас правильно прописаны имя файла настроек и ключ в xml файле и при вызове этого метода то, в приведённом вами примере метод вернёт `true`

Comment: Получается мы проверяемых есть ли данный файл или ключ. Как же тогда узнать стоит или не стоит галочка в выбранном ключе( пункте).

Comment: @Romag, вы должны строить логику так, будто бы вы всё правильно написали, т.к. сложно представить как может данный код не вернуть вам значение чекбокса если вы не опечатались где-то. Но, если вам действительно надо проверить что вы где-то не ошиблись, то есть ещё метод `SharedPreferences#contains(String key)`, который вернёт вам есть ли настройка с таким ключом вообще.

Comment: Т.е если чекбокс есть, то он возвращает true или значение чекбокса?

Comment: @Romag, если чекбокс есть, файл с ним есть и находится в нужной папке, если вы правильно подключились к нему и если ключ в xml файле соответствует ключу в коде то вы получите значение чекбокса. Иначе - то значение, которое идёт вторым аргументом метода `SharedPreferences#getBoolean(String key, boolean defaultValue)`

Comment: все. Разобрался. Спасибо

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46516/discussion-between-romag-and-).